# Is there a 2019-digit number such that the sum of squares of its digits is a square number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Is there a number with $2019$ digits, all digits are positive, such that the sum of squares of its digits is a square number ?

The case is clear if the number has $n^2$ digits. Since $n^2\cdot(3^2+4^2)=n^2\cdot5^2$ is a square number, we can take the number $33\dots344\dots4$, where $3$ and $4$ appeared $n^2$ times, to see that exists a number with that property for every $2n^2$-digit number. and for others cases I made some progress, but I could not figue out the case $n=2019=3\cdot673$. I can't see why it would't exist.

Comment: Also, just choosing all 1s works for $n^2$ digits.

Comment: @RghtHndSd. Sure. I think this is the meaning of "The case is clear." The next sentence is to justify the $2n^2$ digits case.

Comment: Is there any length that this is not possible for? $9, 43, 632, 1111, 32111, 211111, 5421111, 44443333, \dots $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ count the number of $1$'s in your $2019$-digit number, $b$ the number of $2$'s, $c$ the number of $3$'s, etc., up to $h$ the number of $8$'s and $k$ the number of $9$'s.  Then the sum of the squares of the digits is

$$a+4b+9c+16d+25e+36f+49g+64h+81k$$

with

$$a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+k=2019$$

So all we need is for

$$2019+3b+8c+15d+24e+35f+48g+63h+80k$$

to be a square with $b+c+d+e+f+g+h+k\le2019$

Since $2019+3\cdot2=2025=45^2$, and since non-negative combinations of $3b+8c$ form every integer greater than $13$ all by themselves, you have to go pretty high up to find a square that is *not* expressible as the sum of the squares of $2019$ nonzero digits. It might be of interest to find the first square that gets missed.

Comment: The first square you miss is $1$. The second is $4$...

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I thought it was clear from context I meant the first *large* square (greater than $44^2=1936$, to be precise).

Comment: What's great about this answer is that it explains exactly how teachers come up with infinitely many questions which change each academic year, and students who *understand* how to approach the problem from a mathematical point of view can then solve *all* of them (rather than guessing a solution and verifying, or worse: bruteforce approach).

Answer (score 2):

Note that $45^2 = 2025$ and $2017(1^2) + 2(2^2) = 2025$.

In general, this will work for a lot of numbers, because, by changing say $n$ $1$'s to $2$'s and $m$ $1$'s to $3$'s, we can add $3n + 8m$ to our number. Setting $m$ and $n$ to whatever gives us a lot of possibilities

Answer (score 2):

$2015\cdot1^2+5^2+7^2+2^2+4^2=2116=46^2$

Answer (score 2):

Since I saw answers with sum of digits squared $45^2$ and $46^2$,

I found  $47^2=2015\cdot1^2+4^2+4^2+9^2+9^2$

Answer (score 1):

Try $(10^{2019}-1)/9+11$.  Can you identify which number squared is the digital sum for this case?